# Problem getting Java Streams in HP Tandem (Non-Stop)

Tags: java, stream, tandem, hp-nonstop

We are porting a simple Java application between Tandem NonStop systems, from G-Series to H-Series. Java version is 1.5.0_02.

When performing basic I/O tasks like getting output stream from or opening a client socket, we receive exceptions like

`java.io.IOException: Value out of range`

or

`java.net.SocketException: Value out of range`

("value out of range" is Tandem native jargon for, well, quite everything I suppose).

Has anybody got similar issues? i.e. I/O corruption while for example messing with JNI?

I suppose there is something wrong with the system, but where might it be?

Thank you.

EDIT:

adding snippets as requested

sample snippet (a) - using `Runtime.exec ()` (adapted)

```
Properties envVars = new Properties();
Process p = r.exec("/bin/env");
envVars.load(p.getInputStream());
```

Stack trace (a):

```
java.io.IOException: Value out of range (errno:4034)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:194)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess$DeferredCloseInputStream.read(UNIXProcess.java:221)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:254)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:313)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder$CharsetSD.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:411)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder$CharsetSD.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:453)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:183)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:167)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:136)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:299)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:362)
    at util.Environment.getVariables(Environment.java:39)
```

Last line fails, and output gets redirected to console (!).

sample snippet (b) - using `HttpURLConnection`:

```
public WorkerThread (HttpURLConnection conn, String requestData, Logger logger)
{
    this.conn = conn;
    ...
}


public void run ()
{
    OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream ();
}
```

Stack trace (b):

```
java.net.SocketException: Value out of range (errno:4034)
  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:507)
  at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:155)
  at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:365)
  at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:477)
  at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:280)
  at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:337)
  at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:176)
  at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:736)
  at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:162)
  at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:828)
  at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:230)
```

Case (a) can be avoided because it was a workaround for other issues with previous JRE version (!), but same behaviour with sockets is really nasty.

Comment: and full stack trace would be good too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: The problem was caused by a spurious `.so` library.

Answer (score 0):

Error code 4034 seem to indicate that a specific server is not running in your NonStop cluster. Are you sure that your system is setup properly?